# which switch support OFPC_IP_REASM "Openflow"?

Tags: openflow

I am using Openswitch but I have realized it is not supported reassembling "OFPC_IP_REASM".
 I am looking for a switch support OFPC_IP_REASM 
 which switch supports reassemble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests with several switch vendors such as HP, Brocade, Cisco or even Mininet and for all switches, OFPC_IP_REASM property is set to false as i saw in the trace files.

When I search for some information from vendor's web sites some of them says that they don't support this property.

For example, this is the [documentation of HPE](https://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=1839466&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c04777809), it says:

```
HP switches support OpenFlow Switch Specification, version 1.3.1

Unsupported features:
Handling of IP Fragments: OFPC_IP_REASM/OFPC_FRAG_REASM


HP switches support OpenFlow Switch Specification, version 1.0.0

Unsupported features:
Handling of IP Fragments: OFPC_IP_REASM/OFPC_FRAG_REASM.
```

For Juniper, there is a complication. In this [page](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/general/junos-sdn-openflow-v1.3.1-compliance-matrix.html), they say:

```
Junos OS Support for OpenFlow v1.3.1 Features Reply Messages
OFPC_IP_REASM Supported (for MX Series, EX9200, QFX5100 and EX4600)
```

But in this [page](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/information-products/pathway-pages/junos-sdn/junos-sdn-openflow.pdf) for same models they say:

```
Junos OS Support for OpenFlow v1.3.1 Features Reply Messages
OFPC_IP_REASM Not supported
```

If you familier with C/C++, you can look the source code of [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/). I don't know if it is possible but maybe you can manipulate this property from source code.